# Long text in equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, vertical-alignment

How can I write this kind of equation? I've tried a lot of things but I still can't make it. [image: Equation]

Here is my code so far

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textit{efecto de incidencia de malezas sobre panículas y granos} = \text{IF THEN} \\
\text{ELSE} (\textit{período siembra} \geq 2 \text{:AND:} \textit{INCIDENCIA DE MALEZAS} \\
\text{PERÍODO LLUVIOSO} = 1, (1 - \textit{fracción de pérdidas en granos por} \\
\textit{malezas período lluvioso}) \times (1 - \textit{fracción de pérdidas en panículas} \\ 
\texit{por malezas período lluvioso}) \times (1 - \textit{fracción de pérdidas en} \\
\textit{peso del grano por malezas período lluvioso}), \text{IF THEN ELSE} \\
(\textit{período siembra} \leq 1 :AND: \textit{INCIDENCIA DE MALEZAS} \\ 
\textit{PERÍODO SECO} = 1, (1 - \textit{fraccióon de pérdidas en granos por} \\
\texit{malezas período seco}) \times (1 - \textit{fracción de pérdidas en panículas por} \\
\textit{malezas período seco}) \times (1 - \textit{fracción de pérdidas en peso del grano} \\
\textit{por malezas período seco}), 1)).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Woah! This looks like it can do with an `algorithm` environment, rather than an equation...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `alignat` to align every line to the left and `\hspace` for the margin of the middle lines. You also need `\nonumber` to disable the number at every line but the first.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
& \textit{efecto de incidencia de malezas sobre panículas y granos} = \text{IF THEN} \\ & \hspace{4em}   
\text{ELSE} (\textit{período siembra} \geq 2 \text{ :AND: } \textit{INCIDENCIA DE MALEZAS} \nonumber \nonumber \\
& \hspace{4em} \text{PERÍODO LLUVIOSO} = 1, (1 - \textit{fracción de pérdidas en granos por} \nonumber \\
& \hspace{4em} \textit{malezas período lluvioso}) \times (1 - \textit{fracción de pérdidas en panículas} \nonumber \\
& \hspace{4em} \textit{por malezas período lluvioso}) \times (1 - \textit{fracción de pérdidas en} \nonumber \\
& \hspace{4em} \textit{peso del grano por malezas período lluvioso}), \text{ IF THEN ELSE} \nonumber \\
& \hspace{4em} (\textit{período siembra} \leq 1 \textrm{ :AND: } \textit{INCIDENCIA DE MALEZAS} \nonumber \\
& \hspace{4em} \textit{PERÍODO SECO} = 1, (1 - \textit{fracción de pérdidas en granos por} \nonumber \\
& \hspace{4em} \textit{malezas período seco}) \times (1 - \textit{fracción de pérdidas en panículas por} \nonumber \\
& \hspace{4em} \textit{malezas período seco}) \times (1 - \textit{fracción de pérdidas en peso del grano} \nonumber \\
& \hspace{4em} \textit{por malezas período seco}), 1)). \nonumber \\
& \textrm{Unidades: adimensional.} \nonumber 
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image: long equation]

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution with an `array` environment to set the text of the second to the last row, with some manual adjustments to the space between the first and the second line. You need `\nonumber` only once because the `array` is treated as a single line. I modified the page margins to have the equation number not shifted to below the equation.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\textit{efecto de}&\textit{ incidencia de malezas sobre panículas y granos} = \text{IF THEN} \\[-\parsep]
\nonumber&\begin{array}{l}
\text{ELSE} (\textit{período siembra} \geq 2 \text{:AND:} \textit{INCIDENCIA DE MALEZAS} \\
\text{PERÍODO LLUVIOSO} = 1, (1 - \textit{fracción de pérdidas en granos por} \\
\textit{malezas período lluvioso}) \times (1 - \textit{fracción de pérdidas en panículas} \\ 
\textit{por malezas período lluvioso}) \times (1 - \textit{fracción de pérdidas en} \\
\textit{peso del grano por malezas período lluvioso}), \text{IF THEN ELSE} \\
(\textit{período siembra} \leq 1 :AND: \textit{INCIDENCIA DE MALEZAS} \\ 
\textit{PERÍODO SECO} = 1, (1 - \textit{fraccióon de pérdidas en granos por} \\
\textit{malezas período seco}) \times (1 - \textit{fracción de pérdidas en panículas por} \\
\textit{malezas período seco}) \times (1 - \textit{fracción de pérdidas en peso del grano} \\
\textit{por malezas período seco}), 1)).
\end{array}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]